# Changing Typescript fonts in webstorm

Tags: typescript, webstorm

How do I change the fonts and colors for Typescript in webstorm, there seems to be a place for this sort of thing for every other language but not Typescript.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the font/colors used for TypeScript by changing JavaScript settings in Settings/Editor/Colors&Fonts. Please vote for [this ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2073) - this is a request for a separate TypeScript color scheme

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Its missing as shown:

[image]

Comment: I haven't got WebStorm at my current location - but when I last looked I think the TypeScript settings were either hidden under JavaScript or WebStorm just used JavaScript settings. Maybe try changing a JavaScript setting to see if it affects the TypeScript code.

Answer (score 0):

I am using webstorm 10:

```
Ctrl+Alt+S

Search for typescript under Colors & Fonts

Here you can change the fonts and colors for typescript only
```